# Can't import modules on EC2 - Flask App

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask, apache2, wsgi

I am unable to import modules like NumPy, sklearn etc within the flask app on an EC2 Micro instance.

Within the /home/ubuntu directory, I have a directory `flaskapp` which contains:

1. `flaskapp.py`
2. `flaskapp.wsgi`

The code in `flaskapp.py` is:

```
import sys
import os
import shutil
import time
import traceback

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict')
def predict():
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
    import numpy as np
    clf = joblib.load("flaskapp/models/saved_model.pkl")
    print 'model loaded'
    if clf:
        try:
            prediction = list(clf.predict(np.array([['0', '100', '164', '150', '1']])))
            return jsonify({'prediction': prediction})
        except Exception, e:
            return "ERROR" + e
    else:
        print os.getcwd()
        return 'no model here'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
    import numpy as np
    print "Imports Done"
    app.run(DEBUG=True)
```

The flaskapp.wsgi looks like this:

```
import sys
import site
site.addsitedir('/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/flaskapp')
from flaskapp import app as application
```

According to the following question:
[Numpy ImportError when deploying Flask App using mod_wsgi/Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269646/numpy-importerror-when-deploying-flask-app-using-mod-wsgi-apache2)

I modified my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` (and sites-available too) as:

```
WSGIPythonPath /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html


        WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

        <Directory flaskapp>
                WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Going to the URL http://ec2-....compute-1.amazonaws.com/predict throws:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
>   the application.

The error log displays the following:

```
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936872 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592] [2017-11-02 22:15:21,936] ERROR in app: Exception on /predict [GET]
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936900 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936903 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936905 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936907 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936909 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936911 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936913 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936915 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936917 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936918 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936920 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936922 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.py", line 37, in predict
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936924 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592]     import numpy as np
[Thu Nov 02 22:15:21.936931 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 11753:tid 140263731681024] [client 130.245.192.4:11592] ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the apache2 was not able to access the directory. Sadly, there's a very little comment in the question posted above, and the accepted answer isn't the right one.

Adding the solution here if it helps someone:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo groupadd www-data
sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
sudo chown root:www-data /home
sudo chmod -R 775 /home
```

This should be able to run